# Changing PS1 only if a certain substring isn't already in PS1 (bash)

Tags: git, bash

I've got this little nifty thing in my `.bashrc`:

```
has_gitbranch() {
  if [ -e .git ]; then
    GIT_BRANCH='$(__git_ps1 "%s")'
    [ "$GIT_BRANCH" != 'master' ] && export PS1="$GIT_BRANCH$PS1"
  fi
}

venv_cd () {
   cd "$@" && has_gitbranch
}
alias cd="venv_cd"
```

(I didn't write it myself and can't remember where I got it from)

The problem is that if I enter a directory that is a git repo this happens:

```
reponamepeterbe@computername:~/directory $
```

That's fine but what happens if I enter that directory again (e.g `cd .`) then this happens:

```
reponamereponamepeterbe@computername:~/directory $
```

And again:

```
reponamereponamereponamepeterbe@computername:~/directory $
```

How can I change the bash if statement so that it doesn't prepend the git branch name if it's already in `$PS1`?

If it was Python I would just do this:

```
GIT_BRANCH = get_current_git_repo_name()
if GIT_BRANCH not in PS1: # or PS1.find(GIT_BRANCH) == -1
      PS1 = GIT_BRANCH + PS1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case "$PS1" in
"$GIT_BRANCH"*)
    ;;
*)
    PS1="$GIT_BRANCH$PS1"
    ;;
esac
```

That said, you're solving the wrong problem; I would store the basic `PS1` value somewhere else and always build `PS1` from that and the current repo name.  Consider what will happen if you `cd /some/other/repo`.

Comment: In the case statement: s/of/in/

Comment: That does answer the question. But you're right, it doesn't solve the problem with moving to a different directory. However since I'm also using Python virtual environments there's another bash function that does other magic to the PS1 so this now works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty confused why you're trying to modify PS1 on the fly. That's not necessary. Here's the tail end of mine:

```
PS1='.....[\!]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")\$ '
```

`PS1` is eval'ed by the shell whenever it's displayed, so that function does get run, and its output gets dumped in there. If you want to mess with it with some more git-fu, just wrap it in another function. If you want some flexible text somewhere else in your prompt, just embed another function similarly.

For the record, here's the example taken from `git-completion.bash`:

```
PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
```

That looks pretty darn close to what you're trying to achieve, except with the branch after the user, host and working directory instead of before.